# getting values View data in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i did this all but now how to get values being typed in Textbox, password box etc in CONTROLLER. I defined all necessary methods, boxes and buttons etc. So the only problem is to get values in controller and then to send them to model for accessing db data

.csHtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("register","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="submitForm"})) 
    {

    <div>
    <i>@Html.Label("Name:")</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxName")
    </div>

    <div>
    <i>@Html.Label("Email:")</i>
       @Html.TextBox("txtboxEmail")
   </div>

   <div>  
    <i>@Html.Label("Password:")</i>
       @Html.Password("txtboxPassword")
    </div>

    <div>  
     <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
    </div>

    }
```

Controller code:

```
    namespace LoginSys.Controllers
    {
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Registration";

            return View();
        }

         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult register(string command, FormCollection formData ) 
    {
        if (command == "submit") 
        {
            var name = formData["txtboxName"];
            var email = formData["txtboxEmail"];

        }
        return View();
    }

      }
   }
```

i'm intentionally using this way of coding it instead of complex and advance one. Just help me to get values in controller

Comment: why dont u just use model to pass

Answer (score 0):

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult register(YOURMODEL model) 
        {
            //db operation
            return View();
        }
```

NOTE: make sure your textbox name should be same as your model name

Comment: no that's another way, then i will have to use LABELFOR etc but wan to do it this way

Comment: if you write ` @Html.TextBox("txtboxEmail")` then automatically mvc bind name & id attribute with value `txtboxEmail`...so you dont have to use `textboxfor` or `labelfor`

Answer (score 0):

You should use viewmodels. create a model for the view that can be posted to the action. However, if you wish to continue your current approach you need to change the controller action to something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult register(string btnSubmit, string txtboxName, string txtboxEmail, string txtboxPassword) 
        {
            if (command == "submit") 
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

if this doesn't work, you can test it by using this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult register(FormCollection form) 
    {
        if (command == "submit") 
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

When you debug you can check the 'form' parameter and see that your fields exists in the form, and get the proper names for the parameters you need.

Comment: It looks correct, have you tried this in debug mode? Does it work?